# how to migrate from AXD to realview

Tags: axd, realview

I always debug our arm project by AXD for a AT91 RM9200 board, but now I want to try realview debugger, it seems it is more powerful. there is a configuration script for AXD in order to remap memory, however I can't find how to use it in realview debugger, so it complain 0x20000000 can not be written when loading image. could anybody who has prior experience for this two debugger give me some advices, Thank you very much!